# Scala mutable queue pop element

Tags: scala

I have a mutable queue.

```
import scala.collection.mutable._
var queue = new Queue[Component]();
```

I am trying to remove the last component:

```
val comp = queue.pop();
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
error: value pop is not a member of scala.collection.mutable.Queue[Solution.Component]
```

How can I remove the last element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for dequeue method:

```
val comp = queue.dequeue
```